# PHP Libraries for Amazon Simple Notification Service

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I wanted to start using the Amazon Simple Notification Service (http://aws.amazon.com/sns/), but I have not found any PHP libraries that I can use to access the service. I would rather not create my own library, I wanted to see if anybody has used any PHP libraries for the SNS service, and if they would recommend any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an [unfinished php client for Amazon SNS](http://github.com/ukd1/Amazon-SNS-client-for-PHP)

Comment: Nice, this one looks promising

Answer (score 6):

The [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp) supports Amazon SNS.

Answer (score 1):

The Zend Framework has libraries for S3, EC2, and SQS so it wouldn't surprise me if the team that built those was working on a more specific library for SNS as well. Maybe [Zend's Amazon library](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.html) will get you part of the way?

SNS is still in Beta, right? That may make it a little tougher to find the library you're looking for.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me either, but the problem is that they have not added one yet. Which is why I am asking